# Trying to use paint inside of a JWindow and nothing shows up

Tags: java, jframe

Hey I'm trying to put a vertical line in the middle of a JWindow that is inside of a JFrame, but no matter what I do for some reason the line doesn't appear in the JFrame or JWindow. I've tried a lot of combinations of paint and paintComponent but nothing has worked so far. I've been able to successfully use paint in another project just messing around but for some reason it won't appear in this one.

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class MaxwellsDemon extends JFrame {

   static JFrame frame;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MaxwellsDemon mwd = new MaxwellsDemon();
}

public MaxwellsDemon()
{
    frameCreator();
    repaint();
}

public void frameCreator()
{

    //Create and set up the window.
    frame = new JFrame("Maxwell's Demon");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800,600);



    JLabel label = new JLabel("Maxwell's Demon");
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(null);

    JButton particleAddButton = new JButton("Add Particle");
    particleAddButton.setBounds(710,100,80,20);
    JButton resetGameButton = new JButton("Reset Game");
    resetGameButton.setBounds(710,200,80,20);

    buttonPanel.add(resetGameButton);
    buttonPanel.add(particleAddButton);
    frame.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel);

    JWindow mainWindow = new JWindow(frame);
    JPanel windowPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel windowLabel = new JLabel("Window Test");
    mainWindow.add(windowPanel);
    windowPanel.add(windowLabel);

    mainWindow.setSize(700,524);
    windowPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    windowPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black)); 
    mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    mainWindow.setLocation(0,100);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
 @Override
 public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("Reaching Paint");
        super.paintComponents(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Line2D lin = new Line2D.Float(100, 100, 100, 400);
        g2.draw(lin);
    }
```

}

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: First, you need to go read [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to gain a better understanding into how painting actually works (and overriding `paintComponents` is not a good place to start (it shouldn't end in `s` ;))

Comment: I would also recommend you take a look at [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) as it has a really nice picture of just how complex the `JFrame` component actually is and why you shouldn't override any of the `JFrame`s paint methods

Comment: Corollary to "don't override JFrame's paintComponent" I think a better class to override is the Canvas: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html

Comment: @markspace I think a better place to start is a `JPanel` as it's not heavy weight and won't cause many of the z-ordering issues related to mixing heavy and light weight components ;)

Comment: I don't like using panels just for custom display, as panels are for laying out other components and a custom display seldom is used for that.  It's about making sure the type system matches the designers intent.  I haven't really looked at mixing component types, so I don't know what impact it might have.